# Correct way to save an object containint a one on one relationship with another object

Tags: entity-framework, object

I have an object that is containing another object, when the DB is empty it saves perfectly, but once there are objects in the DB, i get an entity error

i tried filling the fields up manually before i called the savechanges. inspected the object and the values are inside, but then the exception is happening and it seems the objects are emtpy in the EntityValidationErrors

```
public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Address Line 1")]
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Address Line 2")]
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}

public class Invoice
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Address Address1 { get; set; }
    public Address Address2 { get; set; }
}
```

The configuration for Address

```
HasKey(m => m.Id);

Property(m => m.AddressLine1).IsRequired();
Property(m => m.Postcode).IsRequired();
Property(m => m.City).IsRequired();
Property(m => m.Country).IsRequired();
```

When i want to save the Invoice i get a conflict that the Address values should contain a value like AddressLine1, Postcode, City and Country.
But i am 100% sure it does contain a value before i call the SaveChanges() method

i didn't expect to have an exception. since when the db is empty, it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I can see a number of possible errors.

Firstly, are you counting on the database to generate Ids with Identity columns? If so, you need to notify EF of this fact:

```
HasKey(x => x.Id)
  .Property(x => x.Id)
  .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```

Same goes for the Invoice Id configuration.  Otherwise your database will insert the first record with ID = 0, and follow up inserts would lead to duplicate PKs.

Secondly, you need to map the FK from Invoice to the two Address records. I'll assume that the Invoice table will have Address1Id and Address2Id to point to the two addresses:

In the invoice configuration:

```
HasOptional(x => x.Address1)
   .WithMany()
   .Map(x => x.MapKey("Address1Id");
HasOptional(x => x.Address2)
   .WithMany()
   .Map(x => x.MapKey("Address2Id");
```

This assumes EF6 where your Invoice Entity does not expose properties for the two FKs. (preferrable) If you do expose the FK properties then replace the `.Map(...)` calls with `.HasForeignKey(x => x.Address1Id)`.  If this is EF Core you replace `.Map(...)` with `.HasForeignKey("Address1Id")` to create a shadow property for the mapping.

If you're still having issues, update your question to include:

- The complete class and configuration for the two entities. (Invoice and Address)
- The exact error message that you are getting

... and we can take it from there.